# Add object several times

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'd like to add object `img` in 4 different containers `cont1`,`cont2`... 
But `img` was added only in the last `cont4` container. How can I add that object in all containers?

```
            var img:Image = ImageBuffer.imageStorage.shift();

            var ti:TargetImage = new TargetImage();
            for (var i:int = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
            {
                MovieClip(ti.getChildByName("cont"+i)).addChild(img);
            }
```

Solved.
This function solved that problem

```
    public static function duplicateImageAsSprite(original:DisplayObject):Sprite {
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(original.width, original.height, true, 0x000000);
        bitmapData.draw(original as IBitmapDrawable);

        var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);

        var returnSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        returnSprite.addChild(bitmap as DisplayObject);

        return returnSprite;
    }
```

Comment: If you have solved a question, please mark it answered.

Comment: If you feel that your answer is the best, add it below. Then click the checkmark beneath the up/down vote tool on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Put the new TargetImage() inside the for-loop like this:

```
var img:Image = ImageBuffer.imageStorage.shift();

for (var i:int = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
{
    var ti:TargetImage = new TargetImage();
    MovieClip(ti.getChildByName("cont"+i)).addChild(img);
}
```

This will produce four different objects.. if you want to adress them you can put them in an array dynamically, also inside the for loop.